# Different formulas in jQuery based on number entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, formula, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I would like to use different formulas based on a number entered. For example, if a number is greater than 25,000,000, one computation will be performed. If a number less than 25,000,000 but greater than 10,000,000, another computation will be performed, etc.

Any suggestions on how to make the following work:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="calculation" name="submitted[calculation]" maxlength="20" class="form-text required">
```

jQuery:

```
$("#calculation").change(function () {
    if (parseFloat(this.value) >= 25000000) {
        alert("court determines rate");
        if (parseFloat(this.value)( < 25000000 && >= 10000000)) {
            alert(113000 + (((this.value) - 10000000) * 0.005));
            if (parseFloat(this.value)( >= 1000000 && < 10000000)) alert(23000 + (((this.value) - 1000000) * 0.01));
            if (parseFloat(this.value)( >= 200000 && < 1000000)) alert(7000 + (((this.value) - 200000) * 0.02));
            if (parseFloat(this.value)( >= 100000 && < 200000)) alert(4000 + (((this.value) - 100000) * 0.03));

            else {
                alert((this.value) * .04)
            }
        })
});
```

**UPDATE**: I've updated the code (again) as follows, but am still not having any luck. Any constructive suggestions?

```
$("#calculation").change(function () {
var entry = parseFloat(this.value);

if (entry >= 25000000) {

    alert("court determines rate");
    }
else if (entry >= 10000000)) {
        alert(113000 + (((this.value) - 10000000) * 0.005));
        }
else (entry >= 1000000) {
    alert(23000 + (((this.value) - 1000000) * 0.01));
    }
else (entry >= 200000) {
    alert(7000 + (((this.value) - 200000) * 0.02));
    }
else (entry >= 100000) {
    alert(4000 + (((this.value) - 100000) * 0.03));
    }

        else {
            alert((this.value) * .04);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvotes? Stackoverflow notes, "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." If my post demonstrates the foregoing, please explain so I can fix. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding downvotes (I didn't downvote) but I would expect people asking questions here to at least know the basic syntax rules of a language (I know, it's more wishful thinking than it is reality), or at least be able to debug the code and find out that they have a syntax error.

Comment: @Felix Kling. Thanks for the input. Clearly, I'm an amateur, but trying my best. I don't care that much about points (I'm not looking to find a job through this site); I care about getting some constructive assistance on an issue with which I'm struggling. However, the downvotes are not only contrary to Stackoverflow's guidelines (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), they are insulting and and counterproductive; a downvote without any feedback tells me nothing about how I can improve my question or code. As you can see, I'm frustrated...

Comment: @Ken there were comments on this question letting you know you had syntax errors; how do you know those same people didn't downvote?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you used above is very hard to read and is invalid. You should only use parseFloat once and not use it everywhere. Here is a very simple example of what you should be doing:

```
$("#calculation").change(function () {
    var parsedFloat = parseFloat(this.value);

    if (parsedFloat > 25000000){
        console.log('use formula 1. Number is greater than 25000000');
    }
    else if (parsedFloat > 10000000){
        console.log('use formula2. Number is greater than 10000000 and less than or equal to 25000000');
    }
    else {
        console.log('use formula3. Number is less than or equal to 10000000');
    }
});
```

Comment: Wayne Ellery, thank you for the example. I attempted to modify my code accordingly, but was unsuccessful. (Note: I am aware my code is invalid--the reason I posted my question in the first place was because it wasn't working.)

Comment: @Felix King. Thank you for your input. I updated the code to reflect your suggestion, but am still not having any luck.

Answer (score 0):

After some more trial and error, I figured out the problem. There was an extra end parenthesis within the first elseif.

Here is the corrected code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#calculation").change(function () {

var entry = parseFloat(this.value);


  if (entry >= 25000000) {
        alert("court determines rate");
    } else if (entry >= 10000000) {
    alert(113000 + (((this.value) - 10000000) * 0.005));
} else if(entry >= 1000000) {
    alert(23000 + (((this.value) - 1000000) * 0.01));
} else if (entry >= 200000) {
    alert(7000 + (((this.value) - 200000) * 0.02));
} else if (entry >= 100000) {
    alert(4000 + (((this.value) - 100000) * 0.03));
} else {
    alert((this.value) * .04);
}

});
});
```

Comment: Well done on solving the problem